# Strange label warning in console

Tags: labels, warnings

I apologize for not showing a MWE. The reason is that the issue in question is not reproducible with a MWE.

I'm using the Memoir document class with all its default settings.

I'm also using xelatex and lucida open type fonts.

The document is long and typesets correctly. But the console keeps issuing the following warnings, copied and pasted directly from the console.

LaTeX Warning: Label `' multiply defined.

There are 11 such warnings.

In addition, there is one warning like this:

LaTeX Warning: Label ` ' multiply defined.

I tried searching for both  but the find function does not find anything.

I'll be grateful for suggestions.

Thanks,

Raul

Comment: Please format the warning so that it appears to us the same way that you see it, possibly formatting it as code.  Please perform a binary search on your document to see if there is some specific region or package that is contributing to the error.

Answer (score 3):

When you have `\label{<key>}` in your code, LaTeX processes it by writing

```
\newlabel{<key>}{{...}{...}}
```

in the `.aux` file (in the braces there are the references to a number and to the page).

This is later read at end document in order to do some bookkeeping. Using twice the same `<key>` in the document doesn't make sense, so in case there are annotations such as

```
\newlabel{xyz}{{...}{...}}
\newlabel{xyz}{{...}{...}}
```

LaTeX issues

```
LaTeX Warning: Label `xyz' multiply defined.
```

The key for a `\label` command can be pretty much any string of characters (after macro expansion), but usually it's something that can be remembered.

Even `\label{}` and `\label{ }` are legal, although I cannot recommend using them.

Quite likely, what's happening with your document is that you use some shorthand or completion mechanism that automatically provides `\label{}`, which you should fill in with a suitable key or remove.

Find all instances of `\label{}` and of `\label{ }` and remove them (or fill the braces with some meaningful key).